# Regarding DDoS Attacks and Amplification

Tags: http, packets, ddos

As you probably heard, many recent DDoS attacks use different methods of amplifications to amplify the power of the attack. For example, DNS amplification is built on the idea that DNS servers can produce a huge output packet for a very small input packet.

So, is it possible on HTTP, too? An HTTP GET packet is very small, while the response from the server contains all HTML code on the page requested (of course the response is a lot bigger).

So, for amplification, the attacker can spoof his IP address, and send many HTTP requests. The HTTP responses will be then sent to the spoofed IP address.

So is HTTP used to amplify attacks, or is it practically impossible to cause damage with responses from HTTP GET requests?

Comment: I don't think that would affect a client machine since the port at which the packets are sent will most probably be closed. So all packets on that port will be rejected

Answer (score 1):

Well, You have to remember that DNS amplification attack is based on UDP rather then on TCP thus - no connections need to be established. When using TCP (http, smtp etc.) You have to establish a TCP connection (3-way handshake) so spoofing is, of course, out of the question.
There are some HTTP amplification attacks (Though they are not called "amplification" per say) which consist of requesting (or posting) a very large object rapidly thus exhausting the outbound (or inbound - depending on the type of the attack) pipe till eventually causing a DoS. 
In order to achieve this kind of DDoS attack, bot nets are usually used in order to amplify the attack since creating these connections is a major resource consumer for a standard computer and since sources cannot be spoofed, lots of sources should be used in order to avoid access list (usually a Simple firewall or a router rule) blocking.

Hope that helps. :)